# withDuration is ignored during UIView.animate

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'am trying to animate the opacity of a AVPlayerLayer when a button is tapped. Here is my function :

```swift
@IBAction func boutonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if(paused){
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: {
                self.avPlayerLayer.opacity = 1.0
            }, completion: nil)
            //avPlayer.play()
        }else{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: {
                self.avPlayerLayer.opacity = 0
            }, completion:nil)
            //avPlayer.pause()

        }
        paused = !paused
    }
```

An opacity animation is launched but it is very speed (about 0.5s). I tried to change the duration for 10s and the animation is the same

I tried to add `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` inside the animation block with no effect.

Have you any idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of animating the `opacity` of `avPlayerLayer`, try animating the `alpha` of the `customView` where you're adding `avPlayerLayer`, i.e.

```
@IBAction func boutonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0) {
        self.customView.alpha = paused ? 1.0 : 0.0 //here...
        paused ? self.avPlayer.play() : self.avPlayer.pause()
    }
    paused = !paused
}
```

There is no need to call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put self.view.layoutIfNeeded() inside animation block but not the opacity update code. Like this,

```
@IBAction func boutonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (paused) {
        self.avPlayerLayer.opacity = 1.0
        //avPlayer.play()
    } else {
        self.avPlayerLayer.opacity = 0
        //avPlayer.pause()
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
    paused = !paused
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change an animation code to change opacity of `AVPlayerLayer` as follow:

```
@IBAction func boutonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    UIView.transition(with: self.videoPlayerView, duration: 5.0, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
        self.videoPlayerView.layer.sublayers?.first(where: { $0 is AVPlayerLayer })?.opacity = paused ? 1 : 0
    }, completion: nil)
    paused ? avPlayer.play() : avPlayer.pause()
}
```

**videoPlayerView** is view where you have added `AVPlayerLayer` instance.